# Sum of two linear combinations of $u_1$, $u_2$ is again a linear combination of $u_1$, $u_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that the sum of two linear combinations of these vectors is also a linear combination of these vectors.

Edit: My idea so far: $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$, and $c_4$ are all some scalar.
$c_1u_1 + c_2u_2=b$, $c_3u_1 + c_4u_2=b$ also.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $au_1 + bu_2$  and  $cu_1 + du_2$  be two linear combinations of $u_1$ and $u_2$.

Consider the sum, $ (au_1+bu_2) +(cu_1+du_2)
    =(a+c)u_1+(b+d)u_2 $

($a, b, c, d)$ are in $\mathbb{R}) \implies  Mu_1+Nu_2$
which is again a linear combination of $u_1$ and $u_2$.